# Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avcapturesession, interrupt-handling

I am implementing Pause-Resume Camera for iOS using this
[CameraEngine](http://www.gdcl.co.uk/iOS/). The problem is that when a user receives a phone call and accepts it, the camera preview screen is stuck. During the phone call I can see this error twice

```
ValidateRequiredFields: Unknown selected data source for Port iPhone
Microphone (type: MicrophoneBuiltIn)
```

Is it possible to restart it?

Also is there a way how to generate this interruption another way then calling on the phone and accepting it because debugging can get quite expensive then. I have tried Siri but it doesn't produce this problem.

Comment: have you found a solution to this problem?

Comment: well I have switched to different camera engine after all issues I've had. Now I am using: https://github.com/rFlex/SCRecorder